# C program to fill an n x n matrix in a spiral form

Tags: c, matrix, design-patterns, spiral

I am implementing a C program using functions to fill a square matrix in a spiral form.
Here is what I already did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

const N = 5;
int top = 0;
int bottom = N - 1;
int right = 0;
int left = N -1;

int main(){
    int z = 1 /*N = 5*/;
    int Array[100][100];
    while (z <= (N*N))
    {
        FillRowForward(Array, z);
        FillColumnDownward(Array, z);
        FillRowBackward(Array, z);
        FillColumnUpward(Array, z);
    }

    printf("Two dimensional array elements: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // printf("\t");
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("%d \t", Array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}


/*Definition of functions*/

int FillRowForward(int A[][N], /*int top, int left, int right,*/ int Z)
{
    for (int i = right; i <= left; i++)
    {
        A[top][i] = Z++;
    }
}

int FillColumnDownward(int A[][N], /*int top, int bottom, int right,*/ int Z)
{
    for (int j = top + 1; j <= bottom; j++)
    {
        A[j][bottom] = Z++;
    }
}

int FillRowBackward(int A[][N], /*int bottom, int left, int right,*/ int Z)
{
    for (int i = left - 1; i >= top; i--)
    {
        A[bottom][i] = Z++;
    }
}

int FillColumnUpward(int A[][N], /*int top, int bottom, int right,*/ int Z)
{
    for (int j = bottom - 1; j >= top + 1; j--)
    {
        A[j][left] = Z++;
    }

}
```

The first function is supposed to fill the first row (**FillRowForward**), the next is supposed to fill the first column downward and so on until all the matrix is filled.
But when I run it only shows a black and blank screen. No output.
Need some help on this please!

Comment: This code does not compile (`z` and `Z` are not the same thing).

Comment: If you show your code for the 4 functions, we could try to tell you what is wrong with them. But as my crystal ball is currently out of order, I cannot help you without that code...

Comment: You are modifying `z` in the functions, but the calling function (main) cannot see the modifications. You must pass `&z`, i.e. an `int*`.

Comment: Don't allocate big arrays on the stack.

Comment: @Lundin: How big array is "big", what's the reason for not allocating it on the stack, how does it relate to the original question, and what's the reason for minusing other responses? :)

Comment: @JiriVolejnik "Big" depends on system. On microcontrollers everything beyond some 50 bytes could be big. On hosted systems, the stack might go up to 1Mb or so, but we shouldn't allocate things beyond 1kb on the stack. The reason is the infamous bug which named this site: stack overflow.  The reason for down-voting the answers was their poor quality. Your answer teaches an obfuscated and needlessly complex way of accessing arrays, as already told in a comment. The other "answer" should have been a comment since it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @JiriVolejnik Allocating 40kb on the stack is always wrong no matter system.

Comment: @Lundin: It simply can't be said.

Comment: @JiriVolejnik Yes it can. I take it you come from some higher level language like C# or Java? Where everything is allocated on the heap automatically for you.

Comment: @JiriVolejnik Then enjoy tracking down the source of bugs like this: https://godbolt.org/z/x46WWaM5T. Hint: `#define MAGIC` and the program will stop seg faulting. Makes perfect sense, yeah?

Answer (score 0):

There are many fundamental problems in this code that need to be fixed before you can start to consider what the actual program is doing. I suspect you are using Turbo C or some archaic crap like that, because this code will not compile in modern standard C.

- `const N = 5;` don't use implicit int, this should be `const int N = 5;`
- However, the initializer in this expression `int bottom = N - 1;` is not an integer constant expression so this will cause problems. There is absolutely no reason to declare all these variables at file scope, but if you do, you'll need to change to `#define N 5`.
- Don't declare big arrays like `int Array[100][100];` on the stack. Doing so may lead to stack overflows, which are very hard and annoying to track down.
- The loop conditions like `i <= left;` are fishy. Instead of initializing `left` to some `N-1` set it to N and then write the loop condition as `i < left`.
- As noted in comments you might want to pass `z` by pointer so that the caller can know that it has been modified.
- You don't have any function declarations visible when the functions are called in main() so the code will not compile on a modern compiler. Always write prototype format function declarators before main().
- A function expecting a `int [][5]` cannot take an `int [100][100]` as parameter, it leads to incompatible pointer types when these arrays "decay" into pointers to their first elements. Fix this by using pointers to VLA and pass the array sizes: `void function (size_t x, size_t y, int array[x][y])`.

Once you've fixed all of these basic C problems, you can focus on the actual algorithm. If you still can't get it working after fixing all of the above, please post a separate question with the modified code.

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear in which manner that matrix should be populated. I suppose the Z should be increasing all the way. If that is true, then you should pass/ accept pointer of z. Or, since you already have number of global variables, z could be global.

Answer (score -1):

The main reason is that the type of the array that you create in the main function ***int [100][100]*** does not match the argument type of individual functions ***int[][N]***. However, there are more issues in your code.

I recommend not using native 2D arrays in C, it's a pain in the ass. You can pretty easily use 1D array and just transform coordinates from x, y to i and vice versa.

Here is your code rewritten to 1D approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Get(int a[], int n, int y, int x)
{
    return a[y * n + x];
}

void Set(int a[], int n, int y, int x, int z)
{
    a[y * n + x] = z;
}

int FillRowForward(int a[], int n, int turn, int z)
{
    for (int x = turn; x < n - turn - 1; x++)
        Set(a, n, turn, x, z++);
    return z;
}

int FillColumnDownward(int a[], int n, int turn, int z)
{
    int max = n - turn - 1;
    for (int y = turn; y < max; y++)
        Set(a, n, y, max, z++);
    return z;
}

int FillRowBackward(int a[], int n, int turn, int z)
{
    int max = n - turn - 1;
    for (int x = max; x > turn; x--)
        Set(a, n, max, x, z++);
    return z;
}

int FillColumnUpward(int a[], int n, int turn, int z)
{
    for (int y = n - turn - 1; y > turn; y--)
        Set(a, n, y, turn, z++);
    return z;
}

int Spiral(int a[], int n, int z)
{
    for (int turn = 0; turn < n / 2; turn++)
    {
        z = FillRowForward(a, n, turn, z);
        z = FillColumnDownward(a, n, turn, z);
        z = FillRowBackward(a, n, turn, z);
        z = FillColumnUpward(a, n, turn, z);
    }
    if (n % 2 == 1)
        Set(a, n, n / 2, n / 2, z++);

    return z;
}

void Print(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%10d", Get(a, n, i, j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N = 5;
    int Array[N * N];

    Spiral(Array, N, 0);

    printf("Two dimensional array elements: \n");
    Print(Array, N);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Writing setters/getters just to access an array is senseless. Instead of this cryptic and possibly needlessly slow code, you should use the much more readable 2D array syntax. Something along the lines of `int FillRowForward(int x, int y, int a[x][y],  /* ... */) { ... a[i][j] = something; }`.

Comment: It's not senseless - it's: more readable, mainly for beginners, and it's not slow, since you can inline it.

Comment: The "mangled array" syntax is known to occasionally generate overhead instructions and we can't be certain that the functions are inlined either, hence "possibly" - one has to disassemble for a specific target to find out. Either way, we shouldn't hide basic C operations behind cryptic functions.

Comment: The main reason for not using native 2D C arrays is, that until C99, you cannot pass such arrays of arbitrary dimensions to functions.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you would keep programming as we did 30 years ago, rather than as we do in year 2022? And if stuck in dinosaur C90, you could still use 2D arrays as long as the array sizes were hard-coded with `#define`.

Comment: Yes there is a reason: The guy apparently uses an old compiler